# Asymptotic Value of a Function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I am reading a paper and encountering an asymptotic expression:

$f(R)=\sum_{i=1}^{R} \binom{R}{i} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{1}{1-p^i}$

Then, the author says $O(f(R))=O\left(1+\frac{p\ln R}{1-p}\right)$. May I know how this asymptotic form is derived?

Comment: We can assume $0 <p <1$? The asymptotic is for $R\to\infty $ uniformly respect to $\varepsilon<p <1$ for each $0 <\varepsilon <1$?

Comment: Yup, 0<p<1 is assumed.

Comment: There is a more precise answer in the following.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $0<p<1$.
For each $0<\varepsilon<1$ the asymptotic
\begin{equation}
f(R)\in O_\varepsilon\left(1+\frac{p\log(R)}{1-p}\right)
\end{equation}
holds for $\varepsilon<p<1$, but not for $0<p<1$.
On the other hand
$$f(R)\in O\left(1+\frac{\log(R)}{\log(1/p)}\right)$$
holds for $0<p<1$.

Start by writing:
\begin{align*}
f(R)
&=\sum_{i=1}^{R} \binom{R}{i} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{1}{1-p^i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{R} \binom{R}{i} (-1)^{i+1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{ki}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^{R} \binom{R}{i} (-p^k)^{i}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty[(1-p^k)^R-1]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty[1-(1-p^k)^R]
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
0\leq &1-(1-p^k)^R\leq Rp^k&&k\in\Bbb N\\
0\leq &1-(1-p^k)^R\leq 1&&k\in\Bbb N\\
\end{align*}

By taking $p=\frac 1{\sqrt R}$ we get $1-(1-p)^R\to 1$ and
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(R)(1-p)}{p\log(R)}
&\geq \frac{(1-(1-p)^R)(1-p)}{p\log(R)}\\
&\sim\frac{\sqrt R}{\log(R)}\to\infty
\end{align*}
as $R\to\infty$, hence your asymptotic doesn't hold for $0<p<1$.

Now split the sum at $N$:
\begin{align*}
f(R)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty[1-(1-p^k)^R]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}[1-(1-p^k)^R]+\sum_{k=N}^{+\infty}[1-(1-p^k)^R]\\
&\leq\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}1+\sum_{k=N}^{+\infty}Rp^k\\
&\leq N+Rp^{N}\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}p^i\\
&\leq N+\frac{Rp^N}{1-p}
\end{align*}
We have $Rp^N\leq p\log(R)$ for $N\geq 1-\frac{\log\circ\log(R)}{\log(1/p)}+\frac{\log(R)}{\log(1/p)}$.

By taking $N=1+\lfloor \frac{\log(R)}{\log(1/p)}\rfloor$ we have
$$f(R)\leq 1+\frac{\log(R)}{\log(1/p)}+\frac{p\log(R)}{1-p}$$
eventually for $R\to\infty$.
But
$$\frac p{1-p}\leq\frac 1{\log(1/p)}$$
hence
$$f(R)\leq 1+\frac{2\log(R)}{\log(1/p)}$$
On the other hand, for $0<\varepsilon<p<1$ we have $1/\log(1/p)\in O_\varepsilon(p/(1-p))$ hence
$$f(R)\in O_\varepsilon\left(1+\frac{p\log(R)}{1-p}\right)$$

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks a lot for you reply. The deduction is a bit . I read the paper again (https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=183043) and noticed it said the one can be approximated from a harmonic function (which I don't know how!). I appears that, from the given harmonic function by the author, it looks the conclusion is correct.

Comment: Hi. I cannot read the paper... The paper  says that the asymptotic is obtained from an approximation with harmonic functions?

Comment: The asymptotic is given for fixed $p $?

Comment: Hi Fabio. In the paper, it provides an approximation on f(R) with large R(R > 35) by a + (H35 + HR) / ln(p) where Hk are harmonic series: sigma(i: 0~K)(1 / i). The paper did say the asymptotic is obtained from the approximation (which is just my guess). And yes, the asymptotic is given for fixed p. The paper also said the asymptotic form of f(R) is easy to be shown (but details not given), while I felt some steps in your deduction are hard to get. Anyway, thanks again and I put the paper in my Dropbox if you would like to read it. (https://goo.gl/VNnLuE)

Comment: Since $H(R)\sim\log(R)$ as $R\to\infty$, that the approximation $a+(H(35)-H(R))/\log(p)$ is, in fact, the approximation which I give in my answer $f(R)\in O(1+\log(R)/\log(p))$. From this, the asymptotic $O(1+p\log(R)/(1-p))$ is easily obtained as in my answer. I think the paper says that the asymptotic is easily to shown starting by the approximation above.

Comment: Hi Fabio, any idea why can $f(R)=\sum_{i=1}^{R} \binom{R}{i} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{1}{1-p^i}$ be approximated by $a+(H(35)−H(R))/log(p)$? I mean the derivation or the rough idea behind it. Is there any theorem or well-known approximation used?

Comment: Note that $a+(H(35)−H(R))/log(p)$  is an expression of the form $O(1+\log(R)/\log(1/p))$ because $H(R)\sim log(R)$  as $R\to\infty$. Thus the approximation is equivalent to that proved in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio. But is there any more straightforward way that $f(R)=\sum_{i=1}^{R} \binom{R}{i} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{1}{1-p^i} or \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} [(1-(1-p^k)^R)]$ can be converted to $O(1+\frac{p logR}{1-p})?$ Maybe using the harmonic series property $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{i} < (logn)+1$? But I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n$ denote the sum :
$$x_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{j+1}}{1-p^j}.$$
For $p\in (0,1)$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
x_n& =\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{n}{j}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{kj}\\
& =-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{n}{j}\left(-p^k\right)^j\\
& =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[1-\left(1-p^k\right)^n\right].
\end{align*}$$
Clear that $1-\left(1-p^k\right)^n$ is decreasing for $x$, which implies that
$$\begin{align*}
I& :=\int_0^{\infty}\left(1-\left(1-p^x\right)^n\right)\text{d}x\\
& \leqslant x_n\leqslant I+1.
\end{align*}$$
The substitution $y=1-p^x$ can get that
$$\begin{align*}
I& =\int_0^1\frac{y^n-1}{(1-y)\log p}\text{d}y\\
& =\frac{-1}{\log p}\int_0^1\left(1+y+\cdots+y^n\right)\text{d}y\\
& = -\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{\log p}\sim -\frac{\log n}{\log p}.
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, one can conclude that
$$x_n\sim -\frac{\log n}{\log p},\ n\to \infty.$$
This more precise result can lead to what is desired.